# can anyone help me to create nested sidebar menu with chakra ui

Tags: chakra-ui

Need to create side bar menu with chakra ui

Creating nested sidebar menu with chakra ui.Need to  create nested sidebar menu with chakra ui .Thnks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your question is incomplete. But as per my understanding you want a navbar having menus inside. For this you can go to `https://chakra-templates.dev/navigation/navbar` and copy anyone of the layouts as per your choice. If not mention specifically what you want in navbar.